# Magnetic component of electromagnetic radiation near a cooled supercunductor

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

What happens to the magnetic component of an electromagnetic radiation, laser for example, when interacting with a superconductor below its critical temperature? Does Meissner effect appears in such a setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Superconducting sheets are often used as electromagnetic shielding in physics experiments. If you wrap your experimental volume in lead and drop the temperature below ~7K (the critical temperature of lead), you end up imposing a boundary condition where the external magnetic field components must be entirely parallel to your shield.  This is because external magnetic fields are fully expelled from the experimental region when the lead crosses the critical temperature and goes superconducting.  This is due to the Meissner effect.